# I am getting the error below when i try to upload files in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

`POST Content-Length of 17663771 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes`

i already have changed my `php.ini` file and restarted my wamp server but still getting the same error message.

Comment: what changes did you make in php.ini. You need to set  both upload_max_filesize = 25M
post_max_size = 25M

Comment: nginx itself also has a limit for the size of POST, a request and for files. Go ahead and check these settings.
It seems your limit is `8388608 bytes` or `8 MB`, but you try to upload a file which is bigger (approx. 16,8 MB).

Comment: Make sure you edit the correct php.ini file - not the CLI one. And restart your server afterwards

Comment: @srp i already set them....

Comment: @TobiasF. yes i am trying to upload 16 MB file and where do i check nginx ?

Comment: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` should be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Make sure you are changing the correct php.ini

2) Set  both parameters in php.ini

```
 upload_max_filesize = 25M 
 post_max_size = 25M
```

3) Restart the  Web server (apache , nginx etc..)

Comment: have a look at this also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067960/1471352