# PHP ini I cant upload my video

Tags: laravel, php-ini

I am trying to upload my video on my website but I keep getting an error in laravel 
Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException
No message no matter how much I change everything I keep getting the same thing. Here is how I set my php ini

```
memory_limit = 3000M
post_max_size = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M


form 

    {!!Form::open(array('route'=>'profile.store','class'=>'formform','files'=>'true')) !!}


{{Form::file('video',array('id'=>'file','class'=>'thefile'))}}



                    {!!Form::close() !!}


  the controller 

    $this->validate($request,array(

     'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt',


    ));






    $pro=new Profile;

    $vid = $request->file('video');
      $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
      $path = $vid->storeAs(
'introvideo',
$filename);
      $location = public_path('/vids',$filename);
      $vid->move($location);
      $pro->profile = $filename;







    $pro->save();

           return redirect('dashboard')->with('success','Your business is now listed!');



}
```

Comment: You are using get or post?

Comment: I am using Post

Comment: pos the code from where you are uploading

Comment: do you mean the form ok

Comment: yess and controller too

Comment: I did it just now

Comment: did you restarted your server?

Comment: yes I did and i'm getting the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stream the data rather than sending it all in one big chunk. Look up the javascript data api.

Comment: what do you mean by stream the data?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run lavarel, as an Apache module, Fast CGI, developement server ?

Did you check the lavarel validator limits ?

Comment: I just want to be able upload my videos with no limits. I am just here setting numbers and I don't even know.  You tube has lots of videos and it uploads with no problem that's what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M

post_max_size = 1000M
```

dont forget to restart your local server

Comment: ok I will. One question is it bad if I put the memory_limit to -1?

Comment: what do you want from put memory limit to -1 ?

Comment: I don’t want any limits so I heard you could add -1 but someone told me something about it’s dangerous is that true? Or can I do it

Comment: i think change the memory limit its not to dangerous, but what ? - 1 ? can it ? from i know, memory limit is for handling apache service from server which affect to loading speed a website. its not limit the storage of file, but the system. its just like RAM, more greater capacity , more faster. so i suggest dont change it

Comment: Ok I won’t. So what should I do. If my website allows people to upload videos how do I go about that. I want to allow users to upload their video with no problem. Honestly I really thought this had to do with php ini what do I have to do?

Comment: read this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)) . one question, you already using web hosting ? or its still in your local server ? if u r already using web hosting, then you must call the administrator for it or try read the manual find the information, if you using local server like xampp or wampp, go to php.ini and change it.

Comment: if u r using laravel, try [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067336/laravel-max-upload-size-limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067336/laravel-max-upload-size-limitations)

Comment: Right now I’m using xammp when everything is done I’m going to use bluehost for web hosting. I changed it so many times but I’m going to click the link you gave me. Thanks a lot for being patient and helpful it really means a lot

Comment: hope it will help you :)

Comment: I wanted to make sure something. The memory limit has nothing to do with the uploading file but with Apache?

Comment: yeah, thats my opinion