# laravel validate upload bigger size then size in php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, validation, upload

I want to upload a file smaller than 8 MB, but when I uploaded a file bigger than 8 MB, it showed this error message.

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 15735885 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I don't want to change any configuration in php.ini.
I want to prevent this error message.

I am trying to validate it.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'photo' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:30000',
             ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    dd('Photo is bigger than 3 MB');
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: See this:- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php or https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation and https://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/ It will be helpful for you.

Comment: use `size:30000` it works for file size.

Comment: Use should try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067336/laravel-max-upload-size-limitations

Comment: You need to validate on the client(browser) side, prior to upload. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload

Comment: 3MB = 3072KB, that's mean you need to set `max:3000` instead of 30000 (~30MB)

Answer (score 0):

upload_max_filesize should not be greater than post_max_size in php.ini file. For example.

```
    post_max_size = 128M
    upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

Answer (score -4):

try

```
if ($file->getClientSize() < 3145728) {
           //your code  here             
        }
```

this will reject files larger than 3Mb

`$file` should be the object you're uploading

Comment: I think php.ini detect before your code run. It still show error message.

Comment: That if statement would work if written as a javascript function:
Psuedo: If(file to big){ print error message; disable upload button;}

Comment: not true.i have that in my controller and works perfectly