# unable to upload file greater than 2MB in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a CMS in laravel and I am trying to upload a file in laravel more than 2MB and It displays that image failed to upload.

my controller code.

```
    $this->validate($request ,[
        'title' => 'required',
        'featured' => 'required|image',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required'
    ]);

    $featured = $request->featured;

    $featured_new_name = $featured->getClientOriginalName();

    $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);

    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'slug' => str_replace(' ', '-', $request->title),
        'featured' => 'uploads/posts/' . $featured_new_name,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'category_id' => $request->category_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::id()

    ]);   

     $post->tags()->attach($request->tags);

    Session::flash('success', 'Post Created Sucessfully.');

    return redirect()->route('posts');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 6):

Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

or check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067336/laravel-max-upload-size-limitations)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo phpinfo();
```

[image]

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files
upload_max_filesize = 4M
```

Comment: If you have made changes "4M" in your php.ini file then just restart your apache service on server then check upload_max_filesize by using phpinfo() function in the browser, you will definetely see updated value "4M". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the memory limit in php.ini is the best idea.
if you just want to increase memory limit in this function, then use this code on your function.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I modified the php.ini file under CLI path, as well my php.ini file under my apache2.

You can find the php.ini file used with the following command:

```
# php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
```