# Vue / Laravel: How to validate files uploaded from the frontend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have an image uploader on my Vue app that takes multiple files.  I want to ensure they are images and of a certain size and if not, obviously don't upload the files and have the frontend display the error.  Right now, the route it hits in the controller loos like this:

```
   public function uploadAssets(UploadAssetsFormRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $files = $request->file('file');
            $stack = [];
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $fileName = Storage::put('/check/', file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()), ['visibility' => 'public']);
                array_push($stack, $fileName);
            }
            return response()->json($stack);
        }
    }
```

My Form Request is below and has the validation but I don't know how to apply that in the controller.

**UploadAssetsFormRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UploadAssetsFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'files.*' => 'required|image|max:1000',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'files.*.max'   => 'The image is too large',
            'files.*.image' => 'Only image files are allowed.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check files extension :

```
$extension = $file->extension();
$allowed_file_types = ['jpg','png','gif'];
if (in_array($extension, $allowed_file_types)){
//do upload
}else{
Continue;
}
```

for file sizes check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067336/laravel-max-upload-size-limitations)

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel image validation

```
$this->validate ($input, [
    'files.*.image' => 'image|max:200',
]):
```

Note: **max(size) is in Kilobytes**

You can also use dimension rule

```
$this->validate ($input, [
    'files.*.image' => 'dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=200'
]):
```

[Laravel Image Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-image)

[Laravel Image Dimensions Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following rule in your validation -

```
 'file' => 'required|max:100|mimes:jpg,png,bmp' // 100kb, mimes must have image extensions
```